# sending email with cakephp2

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0

I'm having problems sending a mail with cakephp2, I know I can send emails because I have my postfix configured, and I can send e-mails with command line or php. So please, can you send me an example of cakephp2 sending emails.

This is the error message

Invalid email: "you@localhost"
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

I've also tried with the ssl via gmail and it doesn't work either, and it's giving me a really hard time.

thanks guys

by the way, I'm trying the exact example of this url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Comment: There is an example in the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration) using Gmail, did it fail as well ?

Comment: Your email does not contain a domain (e.g. .com), try adding a domain.

Comment: It's already working, I configured my postfix server and redirected to gmail, gmail example of cakephp2 didn't work for me. Anyway, thanks guys =)

Answer (score 0):

Your app/config/Email.

`class EmailConfig {
    public $gmail = array(
        'port' => '465',
        'timeout' => '300',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => '<your_email>@gmail.com',
        'password' => '<you_password>',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
       ); }`

your file = app/controller/appController.php insert this function

```
public function sendEmail($type, $options){
    try {
        $Email = new CakeEmail($type);
        $Email->config($options);
        $Email->template = "email_confirmation";
        $Email->emailFormat('html');
        //$this->idCrudRash = $options;
        $Email->send();
    } catch (SocketException $e) {
        die('Erro ao enviar email:'. $e->getMessage());
        $this->log(sprintf('Erro ao enviar email: %s', $e->getMessage()));

    }
}
```

for user: app/controller/contato.php

`$options = array(
                    'emailFormat' => 'html',
                    'from' => array(
                        $config['email_noanswer'] => $config['site_name']
                    ),
                    'subject' => 'Confirmação de Cadastro',
                    'to' => $this->request->data['User']['email'],
                    //'template' => 'default',
                    'template' => 'email_confirmation',
                    'viewVars' => array(
                        'title_for_layout' => 'Confirmação de Email ' . $config['site_name'],
                        'name' => $this->request->data['User']['name'],
                        'email' => $this->request->data['User']['email'],
                        //'cpf' => base64_encode($this->request->data['User']['cpf']),
                        'site_name' => $config['site_name'],
                    ),
                );
                $this->sendEmail('gmail', $options);`

Answer (score 0):

In your email.php file, please remove the default 'from' value, it overrides your passed param.

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'you@localhost', // remove this line
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In app/config/Email 

public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('no-reply@xyz.com' => 'no-reply@xyz.com'),
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.abc.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
    );

In Your Controller

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

public function index()
    {
        $this->layout = 'layout';
        $this->set('title', "Title");
        if ($this->request->is('Post')) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                if ($this->Modal->Save($this->request->data)) {
                    $to = 'test@anc.com';
                    $subject = 'Your_subject';
                    $message = $this->request->data;
                    if ($this->sendmail($to, $subject, $message)) {

                        echo"sent";die;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo"wrong";die;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public function sendmail($to = null, $subject = '', $messages = null, $ccParam = null, $from = null, $reply = null, $path = null, $file_name = null)
    {
        $this->layout = false;
        $this->render(false);
        $name = $messages['Modalname']['name'];
        $email = $messages['Modalname']['email'];
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->config('smtp');
        $Email->viewVars(array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email));
        $Email->template('comman_email_template', 'comman_email_template');
        return $Email->emailFormat('html')
            ->from(array('no-reply@xyz.com' => 'no-reply@xyz.com'))
            ->to($to)
            ->subject($subject)
            ->send();
    }
```

Create a layout and view for email template.and add the data value that have been sent.